# setTimeout in a for loop with array as an argument misbehaving

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have been working on my second game, which works as follows:

- There is a button and its position changes randomly every x seconds
- The x seconds is controlled by `setTimeout`
- Whenever the user clicks on the button their score increments by 10
- When the score reaches 30 `startGame` calls `Initialize`, which creates a new button using JavaScript and pushes the button to an array called `numOfBox`
- The control passes back to `startGame` with the updated `numOfBox`, which now has two buttons and changes the top/left coordinates every x seconds

The function is being called by `setTimeout` multiple times every x seconds instead of once every x seconds. How do I call the function only *once* every x seconds?

```
var box=document.getElementById('boxId');
var main=document.getElementById('Maincont');
var timeout=[];
var cnt=0;
var scr=0;
var levelCnt=30;
var divcnt=0;
var numOfbox=[];
var fcnt=0;
function createDiv(Name,Width,Height,Background,Margin,Padding) {
    var t=t+divcnt;
    divcnt+=1;
    var Name=Name+divcnt;
    var Nameid='boxId'+divcnt;
    Name=document.createElement('button');
    Name.id=Nameid;
    console.log('IN CREATEDIV :-'+ Nameid+':::'+Name+' cnt '+ cnt);
    Name.style.width=Width;
    Name.style.height=Height;
    Name.style.background=Background;
    Name.style.margin=Margin;
    Name.style.padding=Padding;
    Name.style.boxSizing='border-box';
    Name.style.position='absolute';
    Name.style.top='10px';
    Name.style.left='10px';
    Name.style.color='white';
    Name.style.textAlign='center';
    Name.style.fontSize='15px';
    Name.style.textDecoration='none';
    Name.style.cursor='pointer';
    Name.disabled=true;
    t=document.createTextNode('HIT ME');
    Name.appendChild(t);
    Name.addEventListener('click', function() {
        this.style.background='black';
        scr+=10;
        cnt+=10;
        this.innerHTML= 'SCORE = ' +String(scr);
    });
    var b=document.getElementById('Maincont');
    // FIRST HIT ME BOX IS READY NOW....
    b.appendChild(Name);
    // Array numOfbox loaded with all the Box id's.
    numOfbox.push(Name.id);

    console.log('PUSHING DIV:-'+ Name.id + " IN ARRAY :=" +numOfbox);
    // creatediv is called when score is scr%30==0. 
    if (numOfbox.length > 1) {
        return Name.id;
    }
}

function Initialize() {
    if (main.childNodes.length < 5) {
        if ((cnt > 0) && (cnt %30 ==0)) {
            var id='targetCont'+divcnt;
            divcnt+=1;
            boxId=createDiv(id,'130px','50px','black','0px','0px');
            console.log('Inside Initialize:-'+id+' cnt '+ cnt);
            cnt=0;
        }
        startGame();
    }
}

function startGame() {
    var d=new Date();
    var t=d.getMinutes()+':'+d.getSeconds();
    fcnt+=1;
    console.log('TIME IS:-'+ t + "  cnt:-" +fcnt+' INSIDE STARTGAME:-'+numOfbox+':'+numOfbox.length+ ' CNT'+cnt);
    for (var i=0 ; i < numOfbox.length ; i++) {
        if ((cnt > 0) && (cnt %30 ==0)) {
            Initialize();
        } else {
            console.log('STARTING GAME FOR DIV:='+numOfbox[i]);
            var box=document.getElementById(numOfbox[i]);
            console.log(box);
            box.disabled=false;
            var max=500;
            var min=10;
            var topRand=(Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min+1) + min));
            var max=1200;
            var min=10;
            var leftRand=(Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min+1) + min));
            box.style.background='black';
            box.style.top=topRand+'px';
            box.style.left=leftRand+'px';
            console.log('CNT:='+cnt);
            timeout=setTimeout(startGame,10000,numOfbox);
        }
    }
}

function stopGame() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    console.log('IN STOPGAME:-'+timeout+' length '+timeout.length);
        for (var i=0 ; i < numOfbox.length ; i++) {
        console.log(timeout[i]);
        clearTimeout(timeout[i]);
        var box=document.getElementById(numOfbox[i]);
        box.style.background='red';
        box.style.top='10px';
        box.style.left='10px';
    }   

    timeout=[]; 
}
```

I would prefer to do this in JavaScript and not in ECMA5/6 or jQuery, or using arrow functions. I can provide the rest of the code if needed.

Comment: setTimeOut will be called as many time as the value in numOfbox

Comment: When numOfbox is populated with only 1 button, the code works fine.  But setTimeout is being called more than once within a delay of 10sec when the numOfbox has length of more than 1. That is the reason i have added the time code.

Comment: You have to write code by your own, We can only help if you have any issue, show what you have tried so far

Comment: Probably i didn't put my request clearly. I have the entire code and its working properly till i have only 1 button scenario. But when new button gets added, the problem starts. Let me try to post the whole code. Its just the combination of for loop with setTimeout which is causing the problem and i needed a workaround there. That's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed a couple of issues with your code.

1. You are calling `setTimeout` in a loop. So if you have, say, `numOfbox.length === 15`, `setTimeout` will be called 15 times around `10,000` ms from when you set it. Could this be the reason you're seeing the more calls to `startGame` than you thought?
2. I see the variable `numOfbox`, but since it's not declared in the `startGame` function I'll have to assume that it's in the parent scope. So, in the line where you do

   ```
   timeout[i] = setTimeout(startGame, 10000, numOfbox);
   ```

Realize that since `numOfbox` is in a higher level scope ***and*** `startGame` does not take any parameters, the `numOfbox` parameter (the 3rd argument in `setTimeout`) is really not going anywhere: the `numOfbox` variable *actually* uses is coming from the parent scope. This may be ok, but you should consider what is happening here.

Comment: Appreciate the prompt response. Point 1 is the major reason why i see startGame being called multiple times. Coming back to Point 2, you are right its declared in the global scope and its value is updated in a different function which gets reflected in startGame. Earlier i had a code in which i was passing numOfbox to startGame as a parameter and same being passed in setTimeout call. But the problem was persisting that time as well.

Comment: Can you take `setTimeout` out of the loop?

Comment: Then how will i make sure the box changes their position after every x seconds? The for loop will keep iterating without any delay. Python has a simpler way of putting a sleep statement inside the for loop.

Comment: Right. I get your predicament. You need set up your game so that each time your call `startGame` you ***only*** modify the box that called `setTimeout`. I would do this by passing the index as the third parameter, and change the signature of `startGame` to `startGame(index)`

Comment: The design of the game is "multiple boxes keeps changing their coordinates rapidly and user has to hit one of the box to score points". Passing only one box-Id is currently working. The purpose is to have an array as a parameter 'numOfbox' to setTimeout. I am able to achieve the same in python.

Comment: Got the code working now. Separated the for loop from setTimeout.  The for loop just runs against the arra, iterates over all boxes changes its cordinates and exits. The setTimeout is called after the for loop against the array with delay x seconds.  Thanks for all the assistance,

Comment: I think you should look over you Python code, then, because the only limitation you gatve here is the way you structured the logic. You can pass as many arguments you want through `setTimeout`, but you'll need to make sure the function `setTimeout` calls is defined with those parameters.  For example, in the code you posted `startGame` does not expect any parameters.

Comment: Good, good. Would you consider marking my post as the Answer?

Comment: This is strange. I posted a valid question which was being acknowledged by other users too. I also figured out the issue in the code later. The intent of this website is to post queries and answer queries of others without disrespecting or offending anyone. Not sure why i got banned from the community from asking new Questions?

Comment: You got banned!?!?

Comment: Take it to the StackOverflow Meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com. Describe what you posted, link to it, and get people to weigh in. I'm sure this question did not get you banned